# Getting audio URL from jsoup android

Tags: android, jsoup

Below is the HTML tag for the audio link url,

[image]

And below is the logic I used to get the URL,

```
String url = "https://www.dictionary.com/browse/happy?s=t";
                  
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

 Elements wordBlock = doc.getElementsByClass("e16867sm0");
 Element e = wordBlock.get(0);
                      
 Elements audioSection = e.getElementsByClass("e1rg2mtf7");
 String audioUrl = audioSection.get(0).attr("audio");
```

But still I am unable to get the URL,

How can we get the URL of audio by using class id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `doc.select("source[type=audio/ogg]"` for the first file or `doc.select("source[type=audio/mpeg]"` for the second one.
You can also use `source[type^=audio]` - it will give you both.